# Uninstall Huawei Software on Mac

Tags: macos, uninstall

I am running MacOS Mountain Lion. I have borrowed a Huawei Mobile Broadband USB modem (model E182E) from a friend to check out how well wireless internet would work. I was not able to get it to work, which is not the problem I am asking about.

THe problem is now my WiFi connection is slow. I have unplugged the modem, and removed the Mobile Partner application. I am connecting to the internet via WiFi I've been using before. It is annoyingly slow. I am loading the same pages on an iPhone 4 quicker than on my MacBook Air.

How can I remove all traces of Huawei's software from my computer? I mean all drivers and extensions and anything else it may have gotten its dirty little paws on. I would like my Mac to work at its normal speed again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drivers / software for my USB modem have an uninstaller in `~/Library/Application Support/com.birdstep.saunalahti/tools/uninstall_drivers`.

If you don't find any uninstaller, it's safe to just remove the kext bundles. They will stay loaded until you restart.

`sudo rm -r /System/Library/Extensions/HuaweiDataCardDriver.kext/ /System/Library/Extensions/USBExpressCardCantWake_Huawei.kext/`

There might also be a launchd plist in `{~,}/Library/Launch{Agents,Daemons}/` that starts a background program. Like I have `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.birdstep.saunalahti.autolaunch.plist`, which starts `~/Library/Application Support/com.birdstep.saunalahti/tools/autolaunch`. The plist can also just be deleted normally.

Answer (score 1):

"1. Drag Mobile Partner from the Application folder to the trash. Ensure the app is not running before you pulling it to the trash.

2. Delete the launch agents below by dragging them to the trash.

/Library/LaunchAgents/HWPortCfg.plist

/Library/LaunchAgents/ouc.plist

3. Delete the startup items below by dragging the folder to the trash.

/Library/StartupItems/HWNetMgr

/Library/StartupItems/HWPortDetect

/Library/StartupItems/StartOuc

4. Perform a reboot

That’s it, the Huawei USB driver had been removed from your system."

I would add: 5. Empty the "Trash"

Credit: https://www.blacktubi.com/guide/remove-huawei-driver-on-mac/

Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following command to find out where the application deposited files on your system and manually remove them:

```
cd /
find . -name *huawei* 2>&1 | grep -v -e denied -e permitted
```